# matplotlib charts won't display, when the tkinter button is pressed

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

Hi I am a new programmer experimenting stuff, coding in python using matplotlib and tkinter. When the user presses the button, the relevant function should be run and matplotlib graph should be made by the user inputs. However, the button presses and nothing happens. For example I press 'create break even chart' and nothing happens, when it should take the inputs and create a matplotlib line graph, Please could you help me spot the problem. Thank you so so much, I really appreciate it.
[what menu looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPmY4.png)

```py
    def performance_main():
        global perf_screen
        perf_screen = Tk()
        perf_screen.title("Business Performance")
        perf_screen.geometry("2000x1000")

        label1 = Label (perf_screen, text = "Please enter your total hours of care given this month: ") #input sales
        global sales_box
        sales_box= Entry (perf_screen, text= "").pack()
   
        label2 = Label (perf_screen, text = "Please enter your price per hour this month: ").pack()#input price
        global price_box
        price_box= Entry (perf_screen, text= "").pack()
  
        label3 = Label (perf_screen, text = "Please enter your fixed costs this month: ").pack() #import fixed c
        global fcost_box
        fcost_box= Entry (perf_screen, text= "").pack()
 
        label4 = Label (perf_screen, text = "Please enter your variable costs this month: ").pack()#import variable c
        global vcost_box
        vcost_box= Entry (perf_screen, text= "").pack()

        label5 = Label (perf_screen, text = "Please enter your profit last month: ").pack() #input profit last, to compare
        global plast_box
        plast_box= Entry (perf_screen, text= "").pack()

        label6 = Label (perf_screen, text = "Please enter your goal profit next month: ").pack() #compare profit to next month goal
        global pnext_box
        pnext_box= Entry(perf_screen, text= "").pack()
  
        button = Button(perf_screen, text='submit', command= perf_options).pack()
    
    def perf_options(): 
    
        perf_select1= Button(perf_screen,text="save all input", command=save_all).pack()
        perf_select2= Button(perf_screen,text="calculate profit this month", command=profit_calc).pack()
        perf_select3= Button(perf_screen,text="create break even chart", command=breakeven_chart).pack()
        perf_select4= Button(perf_screen,text="compare current performance", command=compare).pack()
        perf_select5= Button(perf_screen,text="Quit", command=quit).pack()
        with sqlite3.connect("SamaritanCare.db") as db:
        cursor=db.cursor()
        #makes new table performance
        cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS performance(  
            profit float PRIMARY KEY,
            sales float NOT NULL,
            price float NOT NULL,
            fcost float NOT NULL,
            vcost float NOT NULL,
            profit_last float NOT NULL,
            profit_next float NOT NULL);""")    
def perf_options(): 
    
    perf_select1= Button(perf_screen,text="save all input", command=save_all).pack()
    perf_select2= Button(perf_screen,text="calculate profit this month", command=profit_calc).pack()
    perf_select3= Button(perf_screen,text="create break even chart", command=breakeven_chart).pack()
    perf_select4= Button(perf_screen,text="compare current performance", command=compare).pack()
    perf_select5= Button(perf_screen,text="Quit", command=quit).pack()
    with sqlite3.connect("SamaritanCare.db") as db:
        cursor=db.cursor()
    #makes new table performance
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS performance(  
        profit float PRIMARY KEY,
        sales float NOT NULL,
        price float NOT NULL,
        fcost float NOT NULL,
        vcost float NOT NULL,
        profit_last float NOT NULL,
        profit_next float NOT NULL);""")

    def save_all(): #save all new variables and calculations to table
        global newsales
        global newprice
        global new_fcost
        global new_vcost
        global newplast
        global newpnext
        newsales=sales_box.get()
        newprice=price_box.get()
        new_fcost= fcost_box.get()
        new_vcost= vcost_box.get()
        newplast= plast_box.get()
        newpnext = pnext_box.get()
        global profit
        global total_costs
        global total_revenue
        total_costs= new_fcost+new_vcost
        profit = newsales- total_costs
        total_revenue= sales*price
        cursor.execute("""INSERT or IGNORE INTO performance (profit, sales, price, fcost, vcost, 
    profit_last, profit_next, total_costs, total_revenue )
        VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)""",('profit','newsales', 'newprice', 'new_fcost', 'new_vcost', 
    'newplast', 'profit_next', 'total_costs', 'total_revenue'))
     db.commit()
    
    def profit_calc(): #calcs profit
        label= Label (perf_screen,text="Your profit this month is $"+ profit +"after a revenue 
    this month of $"+ total_revenue).pack()
    
    def breakeven_chart(): #creates a break even chart!
        x = np.array([0, total_revenue])
        y = np.array([new_fcost,total_costs])
        z = np.array([new_fcost,new_fcost])

        plt.xlabel("hours")
        plt.ylabel("£'s")

        plt.plot(x)
        plt.plot(y)
        plt.plot(z)
        plt.show()

    
    def compare(): #comparision of profits last and next month
        x= np.array([0, newplast])
        y= np.array([0, profit])
        z= np.array([0, profit_next])


        plt.xlabel("hours")
        plt.ylabel("£'s")

        plt.plot(x)
        plt.plot(y)
        plt.plot(z)
        plt.show()
```

Comment: If I were to judge *purely* from your posted code, I'd say that the problem is that all the `breakeven_chart()` does is create three array variables `x`, `y`, and `z`. That assumes that the indentation in your posted code is the same as in your actual code, though.

Comment: That said, your code isn't a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You have the variables `sales_box`, `price_box`, etc., which aren't defined in the code that you have given. Furthermore, you refer to a database that we can't access.

Comment: @jjramsey thank you, I am not that familiar with SO, I've added to the code now. Would plot() not then create a chart? What syntax would create a chart then? thank you.

Comment: "What syntax would create a chart then?" The problem with your *syntax*, at least in your posted code, is that the indentation is wrong. Because of this, `plt.xlabel("hours")`, etc., are not a part of your `breakeven_chart()` function. Also, you still refer to a database that we can't access. You've posted *too much* code. There's so much to sift through that it's hard to spot the exact problem by looking at it, and since your example isn't reproducible, we can't copy and paste it to get a traceback.

Comment: there are on whole a 1000 lines of code, and i have showed the initializing of my database, i am proper inexperienced sorry not sure what else to do

Comment: You may want to look at this, though it's more geared toward compiled languages than something like Python: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ If you have trouble isolating the part of your program that's causing problems, that's a sign that you probably need to refactor your program. (Note that all your global variables make it hard to isolate the sources of programming bugs.)